VS Code User/Core edition GCPW user or any other created user revoked from local Administrator Group
After installation of the VS code, Codium and VS code insider - after restart or 5-7 minutes of work after adding user to group - user access is revoked from admin group and local accounts are deleted, that were added to local admin group
Created GCPW (google authentication method) user installed user version of VS code, Vs code insider edition and VS Codium.
To make sure, that user will have full access to the system (it needs to have that), user were added in Computer Management > Groups> to a Administrator group.
Symptoms:

After restart or shutdown of the PC - user is revoking from a local Administrator Group
After user were added in Administrator Group, in 5-7 minutes user access were revoked from Admin group.
After deleting user from user group in Computer management and adding to Administrator in 5 minutes after, user will not have any group.
After deleting all of the applications that were mentioned and adding user to admin group, users are not deleted from Admin group.

User need this programs for a work, cannot find any of the solutions of this issue. Event Viewer are not showing errors or any kind of problem with GCPW or revoking accesses.
Maybe someone had this problem and can recommend, how this issue can be resolved.
Thank you in advance
